# Searchable Jcombobox with comboitem

Tags: java, swing

I want to use searchable jcombobox. while you are writing on the jcombobox, it should narrow items by searching the text you write. can you suggest me searchable jcombobox component code ?

I want to use it with comboitem object.

```
public class Comboitem
{
  private String label;


private String value;

  public Comboitem(String label, String value)
  {
    this.label = label;
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    return this.label;
  }

  public String getLabel()
  {
    return this.label;
  }

  public String getValue()
  {

    return this.value;
  }

  public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }


}
```

there is an example like this.

[image: example]

Comment: That's a heck of a lot of "found" code to dump into a question. Please consider narrowing down your problem by creating a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `"it is difficult to narrowing down my problem, because problem is complex."` -- I agree, and that means that it's time to refactor and simplify your code, to try to write code with minimal cyclomatic complexity. This will leave you with small individually testable units of code, rather than a huge hot mess like you've posted above.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: i simplified my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really want is a searchable JList.  That way, the user can see the items still in the selection list.

I had a list of words, so I created a quick JList test using Strings.

Here's the GUI I created with all the words, and when I type characters in the JTextField above the JList..

[image: JList Test GUI 1]
[image: JList Test GUI 2]
[image: JList Test GUI 3]
[image: JList Test GUI 4]

I created a model class to hold all the words.

```
package com.ggl.jlisttest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

public class JListModel {

    private static final String fileName = "words.txt";

    private List<String> wordList;

    public JListModel() {
        this.wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        readWords();
    }

    private void readWords() {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass()
                    .getResourceAsStream(fileName)));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] parts = getWordList(line);
                for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                    wordList.add(parts[i]);
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private String[] getWordList(String line) {
        String[] parts = line.split(",");

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            parts[i] = parts[i].substring(1);
            parts[i] = parts[i].substring(0, parts[i].length() - 1);
        }

        return parts;
    }

    public DefaultListModel<String> getListModel(String prefix) {
        DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();

        for (String s : wordList) {
            if (s.startsWith(prefix)) {
                listModel.addElement(s);
            }
        }

        return listModel;
    }

}
```

The code to read the file isn't important.  The code in the getListModel method is important.  This method builds a DefaultListModel with the words that start with the prefix string.

Here's the code that actually builds and updates the GUI.

```
package com.ggl.jlisttest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JListTest implements Runnable {

    private JListModel listModel;

    private JFrame frame;

    private JList<String> wordList;

    private JTextField searchField;

    public JListTest() {
        this.listModel = new JListModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("JList Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                exitProcedure();
            }
        });

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        searchField = new JTextField(20);
        searchField.addKeyListener(new PrefixListener());
        mainPanel.add(searchField, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        wordList = new JList<String>(listModel.getListModel(""));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(wordList);
        mainPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void exitProcedure() {
        frame.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JListTest());
    }

    public class PrefixListener implements KeyListener {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            String prefix = searchField.getText() + e.getKeyChar();
            wordList.setModel(listModel.getListModel(prefix.trim()));
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }

    }
}
```

The code is standard Swing.  The key listener is the most important part.

As each key in the JTextField is typed, a DefaultListModel is created, based on the prefix JTextField.

Finally, here's the words.txt file I had handy.

```
"A","ABILITY","ABLE","ABOUT","ABOVE","ABSENCE","ABSOLUTELY","ACADEMIC","ACCEPT","ACCESS","ACCIDENT","ACCOMPANY","ACCORDING","ACCOUNT","ACHIEVE","ACHIEVEMENT","ACID","ACQUIRE","ACROSS","ACT","ACTION","ACTIVE","ACTIVITY","ACTUAL","ACTUALLY","ADD","ADDITION","ADDITIONAL","ADDRESS","ADMINISTRATION","ADMIT","ADOPT","ADULT","ADVANCE","ADVANTAGE","ADVICE","ADVISE","AFFAIR","AFFECT","AFFORD","AFRAID","AFTER","AFTERNOON","AFTERWARDS","AGAIN","AGAINST","AGE","AGENCY","AGENT","AGO","AGREE","AGREEMENT","AHEAD","AID","AIM","AIR","AIRCRAFT","ALL","ALLOW","ALMOST","ALONE","ALONG","ALREADY","ALRIGHT","ALSO","ALTERNATIVE","ALTHOUGH","ALWAYS","AMONG","AMONGST","AMOUNT","AN","ANALYSIS","ANCIENT","AND","ANIMAL","ANNOUNCE","ANNUAL","ANOTHER","ANSWER","ANY","ANYBODY","ANYONE","ANYTHING","ANYWAY","APART","APPARENT","APPARENTLY","APPEAL","APPEAR","APPEARANCE","APPLICATION","APPLY","APPOINT","APPOINTMENT","APPROACH","APPROPRIATE","APPROVE","AREA","ARGUE","ARGUMENT","ARISE","ARM","ARMY","AROUND","ARRANGE","ARRANGEMENT","ARRIVE","ART","ARTICLE","ARTIST","AS","ASK","ASPECT","ASSEMBLY","ASSESS","ASSESSMENT","ASSET","ASSOCIATE","ASSOCIATION","ASSUME","ASSUMPTION","AT","ATMOSPHERE","ATTACH","ATTACK","ATTEMPT","ATTEND","ATTENTION","ATTITUDE","ATTRACT","ATTRACTIVE","AUDIENCE","AUTHOR","AUTHORITY","AVAILABLE","AVERAGE","AVOID","AWARD","AWARE","AWAY","AYE","BABY","BACK","BACKGROUND","BAD","BAG","BALANCE","BALL","BAND","BANK","BAR","BASE","BASIC","BASIS","BATTLE","BE","BEAR","BEAT","BEAUTIFUL","BECAUSE","BECOME","BED","BEDROOM","BEFORE","BEGIN","BEGINNING","BEHAVIOUR","BEHIND","BELIEF","BELIEVE","BELONG","BELOW","BENEATH","BENEFIT","BESIDE","BEST","BETTER","BETWEEN","BEYOND","BIG","BILL","BIND","BIRD","BIRTH","BIT","BLACK","BLOCK","BLOOD","BLOODY","BLOW","BLUE","BOARD","BOAT","BODY","BONE","BOOK","BORDER","BOTH","BOTTLE","BOTTOM","BOX","BOY","BRAIN","BRANCH","BREAK","BREATH","BRIDGE","BRIEF","BRIGHT","BRING","BROAD","BROTHER","BUDGET","BUILD","BUILDING","BURN","BUS","BUSINESS","BUSY","BUT","BUY","BY","CABINET","CALL","CAMPAIGN","CAN","CANDIDATE","CAPABLE","CAPACITY","CAPITAL","CAR","CARD","CARE","CAREER","CAREFUL","CAREFULLY","CARRY","CASE","CASH","CAT","CATCH","CATEGORY","CAUSE","CELL","CENTRAL","CENTRE","CENTURY","CERTAIN","CERTAINLY","CHAIN","CHAIR","CHAIRMAN","CHALLENGE","CHANCE","CHANGE","CHANNEL","CHAPTER","CHARACTER","CHARACTERISTIC","CHARGE","CHEAP","CHECK","CHEMICAL","CHIEF","CHILD","CHOICE","CHOOSE","CHURCH","CIRCLE","CIRCUMSTANCE","CITIZEN","CITY","CIVIL","CLAIM","CLASS","CLEAN","CLEAR","CLEARLY","CLIENT","CLIMB","CLOSE","CLOSELY","CLOTHES","CLUB","COAL","CODE","COFFEE","COLD","COLLEAGUE","COLLECT","COLLECTION","COLLEGE","COLOUR","COMBINATION","COMBINE","COME","COMMENT","COMMERCIAL","COMMISSION","COMMIT","COMMITMENT","COMMITTEE","COMMON","COMMUNICATION","COMMUNITY","COMPANY","COMPARE","COMPARISON","COMPETITION","COMPLETE","COMPLETELY","COMPLEX","COMPONENT","COMPUTER","CONCENTRATE","CONCENTRATION","CONCEPT","CONCERN","CONCERNED","CONCLUDE","CONCLUSION","CONDITION","CONDUCT","CONFERENCE","CONFIDENCE","CONFIRM","CONFLICT","CONGRESS","CONNECT","CONNECTION","CONSEQUENCE","CONSERVATIVE","CONSIDER","CONSIDERABLE","CONSIDERATION","CONSIST","CONSTANT","CONSTRUCTION","CONSUMER","CONTACT","CONTAIN","CONTENT","CONTEXT","CONTINUE","CONTRACT","CONTRAST","CONTRIBUTE","CONTRIBUTION","CONTROL","CONVENTION","CONVERSATION","COPY","CORNER","CORPORATE","CORRECT","COS","COST","COULD","COUNCIL","COUNT","COUNTRY","COUNTY","COUPLE","COURSE","COURT","COVER","CREATE","CREATION","CREDIT","CRIME","CRIMINAL","CRISIS","CRITERION","CRITICAL","CRITICISM","CROSS","CROWD","CRY","CULTURAL","CULTURE","CUP","CURRENT","CURRENTLY","CURRICULUM","CUSTOMER","CUT","DAMAGE","DANGER","DANGEROUS","DARK","DATA","DATE","DAUGHTER","DAY","DEAD","DEAL","DEATH","DEBATE","DEBT","DECADE","DECIDE","DECISION","DECLARE","DEEP","DEFENCE","DEFENDANT","DEFINE","DEFINITION","DEGREE","DELIVER","DEMAND","DEMOCRATIC","DEMONSTRATE","DENY","DEPARTMENT","DEPEND","DEPUTY","DERIVE","DESCRIBE","DESCRIPTION","DESIGN","DESIRE","DESK","DESPITE","DESTROY","DETAIL","DETAILED","DETERMINE","DEVELOP","DEVELOPMENT","DEVICE","DIE","DIFFERENCE","DIFFERENT","DIFFICULT","DIFFICULTY","DINNER","DIRECT","DIRECTION","DIRECTLY","DIRECTOR","DISAPPEAR","DISCIPLINE","DISCOVER","DISCUSS","DISCUSSION","DISEASE","DISPLAY","DISTANCE","DISTINCTION","DISTRIBUTION","DISTRICT","DIVIDE","DIVISION","DO","DOCTOR","DOCUMENT","DOG","DOMESTIC","DOOR","DOUBLE","DOUBT","DOWN","DRAW","DRAWING","DREAM","DRESS","DRINK","DRIVE","DRIVER","DROP","DRUG","DRY","DUE","DURING","DUTY","EACH","EAR","EARLY","EARN","EARTH","EASILY","EAST","EASY","EAT","ECONOMIC","ECONOMY","EDGE","EDITOR","EDUCATION","EDUCATIONAL","EFFECT","EFFECTIVE","EFFECTIVELY","EFFORT","EGG","EITHER","ELDERLY","ELECTION","ELEMENT","ELSE","ELSEWHERE","EMERGE","EMPHASIS","EMPLOY","EMPLOYEE","EMPLOYER","EMPLOYMENT","EMPTY","ENABLE","ENCOURAGE","END","ENEMY","ENERGY","ENGINE","ENGINEERING","ENJOY","ENOUGH","ENSURE","ENTER","ENTERPRISE","ENTIRE","ENTIRELY","ENTITLE","ENTRY","ENVIRONMENT","ENVIRONMENTAL","EQUAL","EQUALLY","EQUIPMENT","ERROR","ESCAPE","ESPECIALLY","ESSENTIAL","ESTABLISH","ESTABLISHMENT","ESTATE","ESTIMATE","EVEN","EVENING","EVENT","EVENTUALLY","EVER","EVERY","EVERYBODY","EVERYONE","EVERYTHING","EVIDENCE","EXACTLY","EXAMINATION","EXAMINE","EXAMPLE","EXCELLENT","EXCEPT","EXCHANGE","EXECUTIVE","EXERCISE","EXHIBITION","EXIST","EXISTENCE","EXISTING","EXPECT","EXPECTATION","EXPENDITURE","EXPENSE","EXPENSIVE","EXPERIENCE","EXPERIMENT","EXPERT","EXPLAIN","EXPLANATION","EXPLORE","EXPRESS","EXPRESSION","EXTEND","EXTENT","EXTERNAL","EXTRA","EXTREMELY","EYE","FACE","FACILITY","FACT","FACTOR","FACTORY","FAIL","FAILURE","FAIR","FAIRLY","FAITH","FALL","FAMILIAR","FAMILY","FAMOUS","FAR","FARM","FARMER","FASHION","FAST","FATHER","FAVOUR","FEAR","FEATURE","FEE","FEEL","FEELING","FEMALE","FEW","FIELD","FIGHT","FIGURE","FILE","FILL","FILM","FINAL","FINALLY","FINANCE","FINANCIAL","FIND","FINDING","FINE","FINGER","FINISH","FIRE","FIRM","FIRST","FISH","FIT","FIX","FLAT","FLIGHT","FLOOR","FLOW","FLOWER","FLY","FOCUS","FOLLOW","FOLLOWING","FOOD","FOOT","FOOTBALL","FOR","FORCE","FOREIGN","FOREST","FORGET","FORM","FORMAL","FORMER","FORWARD","FOUNDATION","FREE","FREEDOM","FREQUENTLY","FRESH","FRIEND","FROM","FRONT","FRUIT","FUEL","FULL","FULLY","FUNCTION","FUND","FUNNY","FURTHER","FUTURE","GAIN","GAME","GARDEN","GAS","GATE","GATHER","GENERAL","GENERALLY","GENERATE","GENERATION","GENTLEMAN","GET","GIRL","GIVE","GLASS","GO","GOAL","GOD","GOLD","GOOD","GOVERNMENT","GRANT","GREAT","GREEN","GREY","GROUND","GROUP","GROW","GROWING","GROWTH","GUEST","GUIDE","GUN","HAIR","HALF","HALL","HAND","HANDLE","HANG","HAPPEN","HAPPY","HARD","HARDLY","HATE","HAVE","HE","HEAD","HEALTH","HEAR","HEART","HEAT","HEAVY","HELL","HELP","HENCE","HER","HERE","HERSELF","HIDE","HIGH","HIGHLY","HILL","HIM","HIMSELF","HIS","HISTORICAL","HISTORY","HIT","HOLD","HOLE","HOLIDAY","HOME","HOPE","HORSE","HOSPITAL","HOT","HOTEL","HOUR","HOUSE","HOUSEHOLD","HOUSING","HOW","HOWEVER","HUGE","HUMAN","HURT","HUSBAND","I","IDEA","IDENTIFY","IF","IGNORE","ILLUSTRATE","IMAGE","IMAGINE","IMMEDIATE","IMMEDIATELY","IMPACT","IMPLICATION","IMPLY","IMPORTANCE","IMPORTANT","IMPOSE","IMPOSSIBLE","IMPRESSION","IMPROVE","IMPROVEMENT","IN","INCIDENT","INCLUDE","INCLUDING","INCOME","INCREASE","INCREASED","INCREASINGLY","INDEED","INDEPENDENT","INDEX","INDICATE","INDIVIDUAL","INDUSTRIAL","INDUSTRY","INFLUENCE","INFORM","INFORMATION","INITIAL","INITIATIVE","INJURY","INSIDE","INSIST","INSTANCE","INSTEAD","INSTITUTE","INSTITUTION","INSTRUCTION","INSTRUMENT","INSURANCE","INTEND","INTENTION","INTEREST","INTERESTED","INTERESTING","INTERNAL","INTERNATIONAL","INTERPRETATION","INTERVIEW","INTO","INTRODUCE","INTRODUCTION","INVESTIGATE","INVESTIGATION","INVESTMENT","INVITE","INVOLVE","IRON","IS","ISLAND","ISSUE","IT","ITEM","ITS","ITSELF","JOB","JOIN","JOINT","JOURNEY","JUDGE","JUMP","JUST","JUSTICE","KEEP","KEY","KID","KILL","KIND","KING","KITCHEN","KNEE","KNOW","KNOWLEDGE","LABOUR","LACK","LADY","LAND","LANGUAGE","LARGE","LARGELY","LAST","LATE","LATER","LATTER","LAUGH","LAUNCH","LAW","LAWYER","LAY","LEAD","LEADER","LEADERSHIP","LEADING","LEAF","LEAGUE","LEAN","LEARN","LEAST","LEAVE","LEFT","LEG","LEGAL","LEGISLATION","LENGTH","LESS","LET","LETTER","LEVEL","LIABILITY","LIBERAL","LIBRARY","LIE","LIFE","LIFT","LIGHT","LIKE","LIKELY","LIMIT","LIMITED","LINE","LINK","LIP","LIST","LISTEN","LITERATURE","LITTLE","LIVE","LIVING","LOAN","LOCAL","LOCATION","LONG","LOOK","LORD","LOSE","LOSS","LOT","LOVE","LOVELY","LOW","LUNCH","MACHINE","MAGAZINE","MAIN","MAINLY","MAINTAIN","MAJOR","MAJORITY","MAKE","MALE","MAN","MANAGE","MANAGEMENT","MANAGER","MANNER","MANY","MAP","MARK","MARKET","MARRIAGE","MARRIED","MARRY","MASS","MASTER","MATCH","MATERIAL","MATTER","MAY","MAYBE","ME","MEAL","MEAN","MEANING","MEANS","MEANWHILE","MEASURE","MECHANISM","MEDIA","MEDICAL","MEET","MEETING","MEMBER","MEMBERSHIP","MEMORY","MENTAL","MENTION","MERELY","MESSAGE","METAL","METHOD","MIDDLE","MIGHT","MILE","MILITARY","MILK","MIND","MINE","MINISTER","MINISTRY","MINUTE","MISS","MISTAKE","MODEL","MODERN","MODULE","MOMENT","MONEY","MONTH","MORE","MORNING","MOST","MOTHER","MOTION","MOTOR","MOUNTAIN","MOUTH","MOVE","MOVEMENT","MUCH","MURDER","MUSEUM","MUSIC","MUST","MY","MYSELF","NAME","NARROW","NATION","NATIONAL","NATURAL","NATURE","NEAR","NEARLY","NECESSARILY","NECESSARY","NECK","NEED","NEGOTIATION","NEIGHBOUR","NEITHER","NETWORK","NEVER","NEVERTHELESS","NEW","NEWS","NEWSPAPER","NEXT","NICE","NIGHT","NO","NOBODY","NOD","NOISE","NONE","NOR","NORMAL","NORMALLY","NORTH","NORTHERN","NOSE","NOT","NOTE","NOTHING","NOTICE","NOTION","NOW","NUCLEAR","NUMBER","NURSE","OBJECT","OBJECTIVE","OBSERVATION","OBSERVE","OBTAIN","OBVIOUS","OBVIOUSLY","OCCASION","OCCUR","ODD","OF","OFF","OFFENCE","OFFER","OFFICE","OFFICER","OFFICIAL","OFTEN","OIL","OKAY","OLD","ON","ONCE","ONE","ONLY","ONTO","OPEN","OPERATE","OPERATION","OPINION","OPPORTUNITY","OPPOSITION","OPTION","OR","ORDER","ORDINARY","ORGANISATION","ORGANISE","ORGANIZATION","ORIGIN","ORIGINAL","OTHER","OTHERWISE","OUGHT","OUR","OURSELVES","OUT","OUTCOME","OUTPUT","OUTSIDE","OVER","OVERALL","OWN","OWNER","PACKAGE","PAGE","PAIN","PAINT","PAINTING","PAIR","PANEL","PAPER","PARENT","PARK","PARLIAMENT","PART","PARTICULAR","PARTICULARLY","PARTLY","PARTNER","PARTY","PASS","PASSAGE","PAST","PATH","PATIENT","PATTERN","PAY","PAYMENT","PEACE","PENSION","PEOPLE","PER","PERCENT","PERFECT","PERFORM","PERFORMANCE","PERHAPS","PERIOD","PERMANENT","PERSON","PERSONAL","PERSUADE","PHASE","PHONE","PHOTOGRAPH","PHYSICAL","PICK","PICTURE","PIECE","PLACE","PLAN","PLANNING","PLANT","PLASTIC","PLATE","PLAY","PLAYER","PLEASE","PLEASURE","PLENTY","PLUS","POCKET","POINT","POLICE","POLICY","POLITICAL","POLITICS","POOL","POOR","POPULAR","POPULATION","POSITION","POSITIVE","POSSIBILITY","POSSIBLE","POSSIBLY","POST","POTENTIAL","POUND","POWER","POWERFUL","PRACTICAL","PRACTICE","PREFER","PREPARE","PRESENCE","PRESENT","PRESIDENT","PRESS","PRESSURE","PRETTY","PREVENT","PREVIOUS","PREVIOUSLY","PRICE","PRIMARY","PRIME","PRINCIPLE","PRIORITY","PRISON","PRISONER","PRIVATE","PROBABLY","PROBLEM","PROCEDURE","PROCESS","PRODUCE","PRODUCT","PRODUCTION","PROFESSIONAL","PROFIT","PROGRAM","PROGRAMME","PROGRESS","PROJECT","PROMISE","PROMOTE","PROPER","PROPERLY","PROPERTY","PROPORTION","PROPOSE","PROPOSAL","PROSPECT","PROTECT","PROTECTION","PROVE","PROVIDE","PROVIDED","PROVISION","PUB","PUBLIC","PUBLICATION","PUBLISH","PULL","PUPIL","PURPOSE","PUSH","PUT","QUALITY","QUARTER","QUESTION","QUICK","QUICKLY","QUIET","QUITE","RACE","RADIO","RAILWAY","RAIN","RAISE","RANGE","RAPIDLY","RARE","RATE","RATHER","REACH","REACTION","READ","READER","READING","READY","REAL","REALISE","REALITY","REALIZE","REALLY","REASON","REASONABLE","RECALL","RECEIVE","RECENT","RECENTLY","RECOGNISE","RECOGNITION","RECOGNIZE","RECOMMEND","RECORD","RECOVER","RED","REDUCE","REDUCTION","REFER","REFERENCE","REFLECT","REFORM","REFUSE","REGARD","REGION","REGIONAL","REGULAR","REGULATION","REJECT","RELATE","RELATION","RELATIONSHIP","RELATIVE","RELATIVELY","RELEASE","RELEVANT","RELIEF","RELIGION","RELIGIOUS","RELY","REMAIN","REMEMBER","REMIND","REMOVE","REPEAT","REPLACE","REPLY","REPORT","REPRESENT","REPRESENTATION","REPRESENTATIVE","REQUEST","REQUIRE","REQUIREMENT","RESEARCH","RESOURCE","RESPECT","RESPOND","RESPONSE","RESPONSIBILITY","RESPONSIBLE","REST","RESTAURANT","RESULT","RETAIN","RETURN","REVEAL","REVENUE","REVIEW","REVOLUTION","RICH","RIDE","RIGHT","RING","RISE","RISK","RIVER","ROAD","ROCK","ROLE","ROLL","ROOF","ROOM","ROUND","ROUTE","ROW","ROYAL","RULE","RUN","RURAL","SAFE","SAFETY","SALE","SAME","SAMPLE","SATISFY","SAVE","SAY","SCALE","SCENE","SCHEME","SCHOOL","SCIENCE","SCIENTIFIC","SCIENTIST","SCORE","SCREEN","SEA","SEARCH","SEASON","SEAT","SECOND","SECONDARY","SECRETARY","SECTION","SECTOR","SECURE","SECURITY","SEE","SEEK","SEEM","SELECT","SELECTION","SELL","SEND","SENIOR","SENSE","SENTENCE","SEPARATE","SEQUENCE","SERIES","SERIOUS","SERIOUSLY","SERVANT","SERVE","SERVICE","SESSION","SET","SETTLE","SETTLEMENT","SEVERAL","SEVERE","SEX","SEXUAL","SHAKE","SHALL","SHAPE","SHARE","SHE","SHEET","SHIP","SHOE","SHOOT","SHOP","SHORT","SHOT","SHOULD","SHOULDER","SHOUT","SHOW","SHUT","SIDE","SIGHT","SIGN","SIGNAL","SIGNIFICANCE","SIGNIFICANT","SILENCE","SIMILAR","SIMPLE","SIMPLY","SINCE","SING","SINGLE","SIR","SISTER","SIT","SITE","SITUATION","SIZE","SKILL","SKIN","SKY","SLEEP","SLIGHTLY","SLIP","SLOW","SLOWLY","SMALL","SMILE","SO","SOCIAL","SOCIETY","SOFT","SOFTWARE","SOIL","SOLDIER","SOLICITOR","SOLUTION","SOME","SOMEBODY","SOMEONE","SOMETHING","SOMETIMES","SOMEWHAT","SOMEWHERE","SON","SONG","SOON","SORRY","SORT","SOUND","SOURCE","SOUTH","SOUTHERN","SPACE","SPEAK","SPEAKER","SPECIAL","SPECIES","SPECIFIC","SPEECH","SPEED","SPEND","SPIRIT","SPORT","SPOT","SPREAD","SPRING","STAFF","STAGE","STAND","STANDARD","STAR","START","STATE","STATEMENT","STATION","STATUS","STAY","STEAL","STEP","STICK","STILL","STOCK","STONE","STOP","STORE","STORY","STRAIGHT","STRANGE","STRATEGY","STREET","STRENGTH","STRIKE","STRONG","STRONGLY","STRUCTURE","STUDENT","STUDIO","STUDY","STUFF","STYLE","SUBJECT","SUBSTANTIAL","SUCCEED","SUCCESS","SUCCESSFUL","SUCH","SUDDENLY","SUFFER","SUFFICIENT","SUGGEST","SUGGESTION","SUITABLE","SUM","SUMMER","SUN","SUPPLY","SUPPORT","SUPPOSE","SURE","SURELY","SURFACE","SURPRISE","SURROUND","SURVEY","SURVIVE","SWITCH","SYSTEM","TABLE","TAKE","TALK","TALL","TAPE","TARGET","TASK","TAX","TEA","TEACH","TEACHER","TEACHING","TEAM","TEAR","TECHNICAL","TECHNIQUE","TECHNOLOGY","TELEPHONE","TELEVISION","TELL","TEMPERATURE","TEND","TERM","TERMS","TERRIBLE","TEST","TEXT","THAN","THANK","THANKS","THAT","THE","THEATRE","THEIR","THEM","THEME","THEMSELVES","THEN","THEORY","THERE","THEREFORE","THESE","THEY","THIN","THING","THINK","THIS","THOSE","THOUGH","THOUGHT","THREAT","THREATEN","THROUGH","THROUGHOUT","THROW","THUS","TICKET","TIME","TINY","TITLE","TO","TODAY","TOGETHER","TOMORROW","TONE","TONIGHT","TOO","TOOL","TOOTH","TOP","TOTAL","TOTALLY","TOUCH","TOUR","TOWARDS","TOWN","TRACK","TRADE","TRADITION","TRADITIONAL","TRAFFIC","TRAIN","TRAINING","TRANSFER","TRANSPORT","TRAVEL","TREAT","TREATMENT","TREATY","TREE","TREND","TRIAL","TRIP","TROOP","TROUBLE","TRUE","TRUST","TRUTH","TRY","TURN","TWICE","TYPE","TYPICAL","UNABLE","UNDER","UNDERSTAND","UNDERSTANDING","UNDERTAKE","UNEMPLOYMENT","UNFORTUNATELY","UNION","UNIT","UNITED","UNIVERSITY","UNLESS","UNLIKELY","UNTIL","UP","UPON","UPPER","URBAN","US","USE","USED","USEFUL","USER","USUAL","USUALLY","VALUE","VARIATION","VARIETY","VARIOUS","VARY","VAST","VEHICLE","VERSION","VERY","VIA","VICTIM","VICTORY","VIDEO","VIEW","VILLAGE","VIOLENCE","VISION","VISIT","VISITOR","VITAL","VOICE","VOLUME","VOTE","WAGE","WAIT","WALK","WALL","WANT","WAR","WARM","WARN","WASH","WATCH","WATER","WAVE","WAY","WE","WEAK","WEAPON","WEAR","WEATHER","WEEK","WEEKEND","WEIGHT","WELCOME","WELFARE","WELL","WEST","WESTERN","WHAT","WHATEVER","WHEN","WHERE","WHEREAS","WHETHER","WHICH","WHILE","WHILST","WHITE","WHO","WHOLE","WHOM","WHOSE","WHY","WIDE","WIDELY","WIFE","WILD","WILL","WIN","WIND","WINDOW","WINE","WING","WINNER","WINTER","WISH","WITH","WITHDRAW","WITHIN","WITHOUT","WOMAN","WONDER","WONDERFUL","WOOD","WORD","WORK","WORKER","WORKING","WORKS","WORLD","WORRY","WORTH","WOULD","WRITE","WRITER","WRITING","WRONG","YARD","YEAH","YEAR","YES","YESTERDAY","YET","YOU","YOUNG","YOUR","YOURSELF","YOUTH"
```

Comment: @ttn: Yes, it is an alternative.  As I said, it makes for a much better user experience.  But go ahead, be user hostile, and do it with a JComboBox.

Comment: Yes yours is more comfortable but it covers more in the display

Comment: @ttn: In order to cover less of the display, stick to Gilbert's implementation and use an editable JComboBox with a DefaultComboBoxModel<String> instead of a JList with a DefaultListModel<String>.

Comment: i will try to implement your suggestion, thanks Gilber and Costis

Answer (score 1):

> . i changed it to support comboitem object. but i could not set item properly.

I would guess the problem is that you did not implement the `equals(...)` and `hashcode()` methods. These methods are important to implement equality on a class based on the data, not the object itself.

Check out the `Item.java` class found in [Combo Box With Hidden Data](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combo-box-with-hidden-data/) for possible implementations. You should be able to use this class instead of your ComboItem class as it appears to provide the same functionality